# Installing gem byebug on Windows 7 x64

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've seen there have been others who have had a problem installing byebug on a Windows x64 system... Reading over the comments and trying a number of entries I am still not able to get it to install.  Here is the response I get each time I try:

```
D:\Ruby25-x64\bin>gem install byebug
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing byebug:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/byebug-10.0.1/ext/byebug
D:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20180327-5764-1i0l197.rb extconf.rb
D:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- extconf.rb (LoadError)

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/byebug-10.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/byebug-10.0.1/gem_make.out

(gem_make.out Log)

current directory: 

D:/Ruby25x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/byebug10.0.1/ext/byebug
D:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20180327-2084hqddnk.rb extconf.rb
D:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- extconf.rb 
(LoadError) extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Is there anyone out there who can give me a clear solution to this problem.  Thanks

Comment: hi @dannyc1943 is this issue any helpful https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1907 ? try to run `gem install --platform=ruby --verbose`  if you are on windows 10.

Comment: Thanks... That solved the problem

Comment: You are welcome! I answered then. You can accept the answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

As confirmed in the comment, you can try to install as:

```
gem install --platform=ruby --verbose
```

To stay updated, follow this [issue on rubygems repo](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1907) which is reporting the same problem you experienced